# Should I import using iMovie or FCP X?

Tags: macos, video-capture

Am using an old dv with Hi8 tapes camera. Just trying to get all the tapes digitised before the damn things decay, and so I could actually watch old family footage.

Should I import everything using iMovie '11, or FCP X?

When I use iMovie for imports, and playback just the ".dv" files in Finder (QuickView), they look quite good.

When I import using FCP X, and playback the ".mov" generated, they come out interlaced.

Last tape I recorded, when played back on the camera is at normal speed, yet in iMovie, when in .dv format is significantly accelerated. Both Video + Audio is at almost 1.5x speed.

Question(s):

- Why does FCPX produce an interlaced video?
- Does iMovie do some internal processing on the ingested film to produce progressive output?
- What's with the sped up result in latest iMovie tape? Just happens with a single one thus far. Haven't tried FCPX for this tape though.

Mainly:

- What is best to use - FCPX or iMovie for importing?

Any other tips?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hi8 was an interlaced format. FCPX captures it as interlaced because that is what it is being presented with.

After an interlaced movie has been captured you can deinterlace the movies when you export them in FCPX (or compressor) for viewing on computers.

However if you want to  burn the movies to DVD then you can probably leave it as interlaced.

So try that first - burn one of the already captured interlaced movies to dvd and see how it plays on a TV.

Then try exporting one of the movies to a progressive format.